# Flutter map not work with image network , how I can solve this problem

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with the map preview in this part of the screen and when I click on add anything and you have an exception, the flutter map does not work with the image grid, how can I solve this problem.

[image: a problem here]

Comment: With no idea what your code looks like, we can only repeat what your compiler already told you: you got a `403` code from your request for an image. Google has not allowed you access to that image.

Comment: Which image do you try to get? It seems it requires a token or access key. Please add the entire code to your question.